# JSP Registration form gets blank on submit

Tags: java, forms, apache, jsp, oracle10g

Hi hope somebody will help me out...
i am building a small project on eclipse, Its a registration from when i run on server via index.jsp it accepts the value, but when i click submit button it gets blank screen complete parameter list url,
and no record is inserted into the table.
i am using apache tomcat server and oracle 10g database.

**index.jsp**

```
<form action="process.jsp">  
<input type="text" name="uname" value="Name..." onclick="this.value=''"/><br/>  
<input type="text" name="uemail"  value="Email ID..." onclick="this.value=''"/><br/>  
<input type="password" name="upass"  value="Password..." onclick="this.value=''"/><br/>  
<input type="submit" value="register"/>  
</form>
```

**process.jsp**

```
<%@page import="bean.RegisterDao"%>  
<jsp:useBean id="obj" class="bean.User"/>  

<jsp:setProperty property="*" name="obj"/>  

<%  
int status=RegisterDao.register(obj);  
if(status>0)  
out.print("You are successfully registered");  

%>
```

**User.java**

```
package bean;  

public class User {  
private String uname,upass,uemail;  

public String getUname() {  
    return uname;  
}  

public void setUname(String uname) {  
    this.uname = uname;  
}  

public String getUpass() {  
    return upass;  
}  

public void setUpass(String upass) {  
    this.upass = upass;  
}  

public String getUemail() {  
    return uemail;  
}  

public void setUemail(String uemail) {  
    this.uemail = uemail;  
}  

}
```

**Provider.java**

```
package bean;  

public interface Provider {  
String DRIVER="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";  
String CONNECTION_URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";  
String USERNAME="system";  
String PASSWORD="oracle";  

}
```

**ConnectionProvider.java**

```
package bean;  
import java.sql.*;  
import static bean.Provider.*;  

public class ConnectionProvider {  
private static Connection con=null;  
static{  
try{  
Class.forName(DRIVER);  
con=DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_URL,USERNAME,PASSWORD);  
}catch(Exception e){}  
}  

public static Connection getCon(){  
    return con;  
}  

}
```

**RegisterDao.java**

```
package bean;  

import java.sql.*;  

public class RegisterDao {  

public static int register(User u){  
int status=0;  
try{  
Connection con=ConnectionProvider.getCon();  
PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into user432 values(?,?,?)");  
ps.setString(1,u.getUname());  
ps.setString(2,u.getUemail());  
ps.setString(3,u.getUpass());  

status=ps.executeUpdate();  
}catch(Exception e){}  

return status;  
}  

}[![blank][1]][1]
```

**SOLVED:**
Well its quite simple i haven't include oracle14.jar file in proper place. You should include the oracle14.jar file into /WEB-INF/lib folder only.. otherwise you web application not able to connect to the database.